# How to show whether these integrals converge or not?

Tags: integration, asymptotics, improper-integrals

Let's have integral
$$
\int_1^\infty \frac{\sin(x^{2})}{\sqrt{x}} \, dx \approx 0.3< \infty
$$
Suppose then integrals
$$
I_1 \equiv \int_1^\infty \frac{\sin(x^{2})\cos(2x)}{\sqrt{x}} \, dx, \quad I_2 \equiv \int_1^\infty \frac{\sin(x^{2})\sin(2x)}{\sqrt{x}} \, dx
$$
Do they converge?

Comment: Your function still alternates between negative and positive, with increasing denominators for each positive/negative component, and bounded numerators. This should suggest convergence with some extra work, but the mismatch of zeros of $\sin x^2$ versus that of $\sin 2x$ and $\cos 2x$ confuses things (you may occasionally get a numerator that has very small interval when it is positive or negative, or numerators that are positive or negative for intervals close to the maximum possible length). Thus the standard alternating series argument doesn't work out of the box.

Answer (score 2):

[Dirichlet's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet's_test) is the key.

$$\int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(x^2)\cos(2x)}{\sqrt{x}}\,dx=\frac{1}{2}\left(\int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin((x+1)^2-1)}{\sqrt{x}}\,dx+\int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin((x-1)^2-1)}{\sqrt{x}}\,dx\right)\tag{1}$$
and:

$$\int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin((x+1)^2-1)}{\sqrt{x}}\,dx=\int_{3}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(u)}{2\sqrt{1+u}\sqrt{-1+\sqrt{1+u}}}\,du, $$

$$\int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin((x-1)^2-1)}{\sqrt{x}}\,dx=\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(u)}{2\sqrt{1+u}\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+u}}}\,du, \tag{2}$$
where $\sin(u)$ is a function with a bounded primitive and $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+u}\sqrt{\pm 1+\sqrt{1+u}}}$ is a function eventually decreasing to zero. Dirichlet's test hence gives that both your integrals are converging - as improper Riemann integrals, obviously.

Comment: Since the denominator eventually becomes monotonically increasing to $\infty$, isn't the easier to understand (and more well known) alternating series test enough since $\sin u$ is the numerator and it's periodic alternating between symmetric positive and negative components?

Comment: @user2566092: I bet that is just a matter of taste. Dirichlet's test is just a more general version of Leibniz' test, but it has a continuous version. Anyway you are right, to prove that the RHS of $(2)$ is converging is more or less the same as proving that the Dirichlet's integral $\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\,dx$ is converging, and the periodicity of the sine function gives a great help.