# Is $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\prod_{n-1}^m \sin (x^n)}{f(x)}dx$ convergent if $f(x) \to \infty$ is strictly positive increasing?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, improper-integrals

This question is motivated by this question [How to show whether these integrals converge or not?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1445231/how-to-show-whether-these-integrals-converge-or-not/1445265?noredirect=1#comment2944068_1445265) where exact integral reformulation and Dirichlet's test is used to give an answer. However suppose we just have a positive increasing continuous function $f(x)$ such that $f(x) \to \infty$. Then is $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\prod_{n-1}^m \sin (x^n)}{f(x)}dx$ convergent? It seems like it should be, but the alternation of the numerator from positive to negative seems so unpredictable I can't see how to show it, except for the case $m = 1$.